# Copying cell with VBA using If statement

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, for-loop, boolean

I'm a beginner with VBA and I'm wondering how to add a IF ELSE statement to my code:
I only want to enable to copy the cells if the are filled and if they are not filled msgbox must pop-up

code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim NextRow As Range

    Sheet1.Range("F7,F10,F13,F16,F19,F22,F25,F28").Copy

    Sheets("Overzicht").Select
    Set NextRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    NextRow.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial (xlValues), Transpose:=True

    MsgBox "Invoer is opgeslagen"

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to *`stackoverflow.com`*

You have to wrap your *`copy code block`* with a **`for loop`**, **`IF-ELSE`** statement and a **`Boolean`** type variable.

Firstly, you want to iterate over your specified range of cells and make sure they are all filled

```
 Dim allFilled As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 7 To 28 Step 3
        If Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("F" & i)) Then
            allFilled = True
        Else
            allFilled = False
        End If
    Next i
```

If they are you can proceed with copying-pasting and if they are **not** the program will show a message box: **`Not all the cells are filled! Cant copy`**

your complete code:

```
Sub CommandButton3_Click()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim allFilled As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 7 To 28 Step 3
        If Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("F" & i)) Then
            allFilled = True
        Else
            allFilled = False
        End If
    Next i

    If allFilled Then ' = if (allFilled = true) then
        Dim NextRow As Range
        Sheet1.Range("F7,F10,F13,F16,F19,F22,F25,F28").Copy

        Sheets("Overzicht").Select
        Set NextRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp). _ 
                      Offset(1, 0)
        NextRow.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial (xlValues), Transpose:=True

        MsgBox "Invoer is opgeslagen"

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Else
        MsgBox "Not all the cells are filled! Cant copy"
    End If
End Sub
```

## **`Update`**, *from comments*:

Yes, it's possible to execute different checks individually too, for example:

```
Dim allFilled As Boolean
If Not IsEmpty(Range("F7, F10, F13, F16")) And IsEmpty(Range("F8")) Then
    ' F7, F10, F13, F16 are not empty and F8 is empty
    allFilled = True
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("F28")) Then
    ' F28 empty cannot execute copy-paste
    allFilled = False
Else
    allFilled = False
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Mehow, This is very helpful. Is it also possible to make one of the cells F16,F19,F22,F25 conditional. So, that F7,F10,F13,F28 and F16 or F19 or F22 or F25? are notempty before copying?